# Rename text that meets two criteria at the same time

Tags: r

I am trying to work out one question to replace the existing content when two criteria are met. The question asks:

The following three locations are the three most demanded in the data:

- Safeway at 94107 zipcode
- Whole Foods Market at 94107 zipcode
- Pizzeria Delfina at 94110 zipcode

We want to identify deliveries to those specific locations as hotspots.
Tag every delivery at the specific zipcode by re-labeling the 'pickup_name' with a new label:

- Add a label '-H1' to every Whole Foods Market at zipcode 94107
- Add a label '-H2' to every Safeway at zipcode 94107
- Add a label '-H3' to every Pizzeria Delfina at zipcode 94110

For example, the pickup_name 'Safeway' will now look like 'Safeway-H2' at every 94107 zipcode.

I used if function but it does not work the code is

```
if(which(problem$pickup_zipcode==94107) & which(problem$pickup_name=="Safeway")){
  problem$pickup_name<-"Safeway-H2"
}
```

And the console says that:

```
Warning messages:
1: In which(problem$pickup_zipcode == 94107) & which(problem$pickup_name ==  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In if (which(problem$pickup_zipcode == 94107) & which(problem$pickup_name ==  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

The data set is available through this Google Drive link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DEdJvAdACVv_Pc5IcgFBSGvDKm_GPrNE

Comment: you can try a dplyr solution:

`df <- df %>%
  mutate(pickup_name = ifelse(pickup_zipcode==94107&pickup_name=="Safeway","-H1",
                              ifelse(pickup_zipcode==94107&pickup_name=="Whole Foods Market","-H2",
                                     ifelse(pickup_zipcode==94110&pickup_name=="Pizzeria Delfina","-H3",pickup_name))))`

Comment: Hi Eric, hope you had a great Thanksgiving break. After pasting this into r studio. I received the following warning message.  "Error in df %>% mutate(pickup_name = ifelse(dropoff_zipcode == 94107 &  : 
  could not find function "%>%""

Comment: Nan,  that error mean that R doesn't recognize the pipe operator.  This happens when the `Magrittr` package is not loaded.  I suggest that you install `tidyverse` first: `install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies=T)` and then load it up up with: `library(tidyverse)` before you run the code above.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. `mutate` is the function to create or update a column. `case_when` is a way to specify condition and replacement. Assuming that your data frame is called `dt`. `dt2` is the data frame after replacement.

```
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(pickup_name = case_when(
    pickup_name %in% "Whole Foods Market" & pickup_zipcode %in% 94107 ~ paste0(pickup_name, "-H1"),
    pickup_name %in% "Safeway" & pickup_zipcode %in% 94107            ~ paste0(pickup_name, "-H2"),
    pickup_name %in% "Pizzeria Delfina" & pickup_zipcode %in% 94110   ~ paste0(pickup_name, "-H3"),
    TRUE                                                              ~ pickup_name
  ))
```

Comment: Hi www, hope you had a great thanksgiving break. After pasting your code and adjust some names. I got the following messages.         "Error in problem %>% mutate(pickup_name = case_when(pickup_name %in% "Whole Foods Market" &  : 
  could not find function "%>%""

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use an if statement. Just subset the data to what you want and set it equal to the new value:

```
problem[problem$pickup_zipcode == 91407 & problem$pickup_name == "Safeway", ]$pickup_name <- "Safeway-H2"
```

Comment: Hi Ian, hope you had a great thanksgiving break. After pasting the code into r studio, I received the following message "Error: unexpected symbol in "problem[problem$dropoff_zipcode == 94107 & problem$pickup_name == "Safeway", ]problem""